# Crackling/clicking sound while recording audio Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, usb, pulseaudio, microphone

I record audio using USB microphones. In all the recorded audio from all the microphones, there is a crackling/clicking sound. It's not continuous though. I changed the cable, tried different USB hubs (both USB 2.0 and 3.0 hubs), changed sample rate to 48000 in PulseAudio, added and removed autosuspend=-1 in grub file, but none of these worked.

If anybody can provide solution to solve this problem, it will be really great.

Providing below details just in case it's needed.

```
uname -a

Linux THNKPD-P52 5.15.0-67-lowlatency #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 22 17:01:40 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Laptop: ThinkPad P52

Software used for recording audio: Audacity and GNome Audio Recorder.

External Sound Card: Creative Sound Blaster X4

USB Microphones: sE Neom, Rode NT-USB+ and Shure MV51

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the crackling sound was because of the powered USB Hub which was connected to the same USB hub to which microphones were connected. I connected the powered USB hub to the laptop directly and it worked. Just for testing purpose I connected the powered USB hub to different USB hub and it worked too. There is no crackling / clicking sound any more in recorded audio.